# PHP new value declared in a function isnt being saved/kept [PHP]

Tags: php, html, css, web

If you were to declare a global variable as one value, then change it via execution of another function, the original value is going to be kept instead of the update.

Example:

```
<?php 

global $initial;
$initial = 1;


if ($initial == 0) {
     if(isset($_POST['prev'])) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of -1 month', strtotime($currentDate)));
    }
        if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
            echo $GLOBALS[$ar];
            global $currentDate;
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of +1 month', strtotime($currentDate)));
            $GLOBALS[$ar] = "Hallo Welt: 14";
        }
    } else {
        global $initial;
        $initial = 0;
    }
?>
```

the Buttons are being executed on Button press event via the:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="prev" value="<">
    <input type="submit" name="next" value=">">
</form>
```

Comment: Keyword `global` is for _importing_ a variable into a narrower scope, not for declaring a variable global

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php